# How to Export or Bookmark lines not exist or duplicated in another text file

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, text-editing

my system available in: Windows 7 - Windows 2012

using Text Editor: Emeditor - Notepad++

i have 2 text files

first .txt 64512 lines

second .txt 64177 lines

how do i export or bookmark the lines not exist in the second .txt 64177, from the first .txt 64512

or remove all the lines that exist in second .txt file 64177, from the first .txt file 64512

so exactly there 335 lines in the first .txt file not exist in the second .txt file i want to export or bookmark them

"important" every line with different letters-numbers so the Example is just for explaining

Simple Example: "first .txt file" look like

```
unknown1:randomstest2
Exportme7:bookmarkit8
unknown3:randomstest4
allstars:Superhero1
unknown5:randomstest6
exportme1:Bookmarkit2
unKnown7:randomstest8
allgolden:markmetest2
unknown9:randomstest10
unknown11:randomstest12
exportme3:bookmarkit4
unknown13:randomstest14
exportme5:bookmarkit6
unknown15:randomstest16
Goldroad:Avatar3
unknown17:randomstest18
```

Simple Example: "second .txt file" look like

```
unknown11:randomstest12
unknown3:randomstest4
unknown17:randomstest18
unknown5:randomstest6
unknown15:randomstest16
unKnown7:randomstest8
unknown9:randomstest10
unknown13:randomstest14
unknown1:randomstest2
```

Need Result: from "first .txt file" to check "second .txt file" and export or bookmark the not duplicated lines

```
exportme5:bookmarkit6
Goldroad:Avatar3
exportme3:bookmarkit4
allstars:Superhero1
allgolden:markmetest2
Exportme7:bookmarkit8
exportme1:Bookmarkit2
```

anyone can help please ? i appreciate it so much

Comment: You can't do that with Notepad++, you have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Comment: Did you consider `VLOOKUP()` in Excel to find matching records? (Using right tool for a job.)